# What is the best way to get coordinate from google map url?

Tags: php, google-maps

I have written a php function to get coordinate from google map url

this function get all coordinate (lat, lng) in the url

If more than one coordinate in the url, it will get each coordinate and save in array

e.g.

In first url, I want to get this coordinate `39.0101036,30.6895281`

In second url, I want to get `44.2850711,25.4921039` `44.2897146,25.4775629` `44.28462,25.5294405`

It can handles two cases

```
$url="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Turkey/@39.0101036,30.6895281,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14b0155c964f2671:0x40d9dbd42a625f2a!8m2!3d38.9893026!4d35.4364014?hl=en";
$url="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Videle/44.2850711,25.4921039/44.2897146,25.4775629/44.28462,25.5294405/@44.2801102,25.4944293,14z/data=!4m11!4m10!1m5!1m1!1s0x40ade955dedb9419:0xe28ca19380f0b772!2m2!1d25.5332629!2d44.2748537!1m0!1m0!1m0!3e2?hl=en";
```

But I am not sure it is enough to handle every cases

Please tell me if there is any case which cannot be handled by my function

```
function urlToCoor($url){
    $originalUrl=$url;

    $coor=array();
    $at=strpos($url, "@");
    $url=substr($url, $at+1);

    $o=new Location();

    //get lat
    $comma=strpos($url, ",");
    $lat=substr($url, 0, $comma);
    $url=substr($url, $comma+1);

    //get lng
    $comma=strpos($url, ",");
    $lng=substr($url, 0, $comma);
    $url=substr($url, $comma+1);

    $o->lat=$lat;
    $o->lng=$lng;

    array_push($coor, $o);

    //get other coor
    if(strpos($originalUrl, '/dir/Videle/')){
        $coor=array();
        $start=strpos($originalUrl, '/dir/Videle/')+12;
        $end=strpos($originalUrl, '/@');
        $url=substr($originalUrl, $start, $end - $start);

        $otherCoor=explode('/', $url);
        foreach($otherCoor as $value){
            $lat=explode(',', $value)[0];
            $lng=explode(',', $value)[1];

            $o=new Location();
            $o->lat=$lat;
            $o->lng=$lng;

            array_push($coor, $o);
        }
    }else if(strpos($originalUrl, '/dir/')){
        $coor=array();
        $start=strpos($originalUrl, '/dir/')+5;
        $end=strpos($originalUrl, '/@');
        $url=substr($originalUrl, $start, $end - $start);

        $otherCoor=explode('/', $url);
        foreach($otherCoor as $value){
            $lat=explode(',', $value)[0];
            $lng=explode(',', $value)[1];

            $o=new Location();
            $o->lat=$lat;
            $o->lng=$lng;

            array_push($coor, $o);
        }
    }
    return $coor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is probably a better choice than strpos in this case.

https://regex101.com/r/txBSa9/1

```
$re = '/@(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)/';


$str = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Turkey/@39.0101036,30.6895281,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14b0155c964f2671:0x40d9dbd42a625f2a!8m2!3d38.9893026!4d35.4364014?hl=en
https ://www.google.com/maps/dir/Videle/44.2850711,25.4921039/44.2897146,25.4775629/44.28462,25.5294405/@44.2801102,25.4944293,14z/data=!4m11!4m10!1m5!1m1!1s0x40ade955dedb9419:0xe28ca19380f0b772!2m2!1d25.5332629!2d44.2748537!1m0!1m0!1m0!3e2?hl=en';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

This will match `@` and digits with dots separated with comma.

$array[1] will hold a subarray with the following;

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) 
"39.0101036,30.6895281"
    [1]=>
    string(21) 
"44.2801102,25.4944293"
  }
```

Update:

Try this then. https://3v4l.org/pgDRN
It will get all lat/lon in the links and save them in separate arrays.

$matches[0] is the full match, meaning both lat and lon.

$matches[1] is the lats.

$matches[2] is the lons.

```
$re = '/(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)/';


$str = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Turkey/@39.0101036,30.6895281,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14b0155c964f2671:0x40d9dbd42a625f2a!8m2!3d38.9893026!4d35.4364014?hl=en
https ://www.google.com/maps/dir/Videle/44.2850711,25.4921039/44.2897146,25.4775629/44.28462,25.5294405/@44.2801102,25.4944293,14z/data=!4m11!4m10!1m5!1m1!1s0x40ade955dedb9419:0xe28ca19380f0b772!2m2!1d25.5332629!2d44.2748537!1m0!1m0!1m0!3e2?hl=en';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: I just updated my function , because I found a problem, if `/dir/` exists in the url, I should not get the `@xxxxx,xxxxx`, because it is just the coordinate of screen

Comment: Update your question with link and what you want to extract from each link. It's hard work to read your code.